# mysql_store_result() @ MySQL C API - does it really allocate memory in each call?

Tags: mysql, c, api

I've read that mysql_store_result() in the MySQL C API will allocate memory for each and every call to it;

```
mysql_store_result() reads the entire result of a query to the client, allocates a MYSQL_RES structure, and places the result into this structure.
```

It is really so?
I'm asking because I'm about to call it many times in a server application.
Allocating/Freeing is horrible for my purpose.

Is there a way to provide a custom buffer to it? Maybe some "undocumented" API?

Comment: is there a reason you don't use mysql_use_result / mysql_fetch_row instead? that doesn't cache the whole result set in memory and would allow you to build a custom buffer.

Comment: Are you sure about that? I'll check it right away then.

Comment: As far as I understand the docs, the mysql_use_result() function returns a pointer to a MYSQL_RES structure. Who allocated that one? Not me for sure. That's my concern. And, I also have to free that with mysql_free_result(). Doesn't that mean that there's a malloc()/free() calls? Correct me.

Comment: ya, you have to free it with mysql_free_result after you're done. but its just a small internal buffer for use_result, a much bigger one for store_result.

Comment: what's the issue with not wanting to alloc/free memory, if you don't mind my asking (just curious)

Comment: Sure, well, a server application would run 24/7.
Memory fragmentation is possible on the long run. Besides, when you allocate some memory, a certain lock() is being used, thus slowing things down.
I hope someone comes with a solution - I can't believe they didn't think of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this link about using mysql_use_result:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-use-result.html

i use "use_result" instead of "store_result" on all select queries.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's really so.  Why wouldn't it be?

Perhaps you mean to edit your question to be, "What can I do instead?" rather than "Is it really so?"  Based on your comments, that seems to be more what you're actually wanting to know.